# Merge tags [jigsaw] and [java-module]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both of these refer to the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) -- technically the JPMS is a "[component](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/)" of [Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), but in practice the JPMS was Jigsaw's main deliverable, and questions tagged [jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jigsaw) are overwhelmingly about the module system, not about other aspects of Jigsaw such as the application of the module system to the Java platform. There's no obvious systematic difference between questions tagged one or the other, and in fact many questions are already tagged with both.

Answer (score 2):

**Tl;DR** Both tags have the right to exist.

[jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jigsaw)155 Open Qs 32 watchers

> Project Jigsaw aims to design and implement a standard module system for the Java SE platform. It was released as part of Java 9.

[java-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-module) 174 Open Qs 8 watchers

> Refers to the module as defined by the module system in java introduced in Java9. Hence likely to be coupled with Java9 (or above) tag.

Both: 31 Open Qs

5 names of the 8 most prolific answerers in each of the All Time Top Answerers' lists are the same.

A merge would not be appropriate because, even if in practice the two tags are used to mean much the same thing their Usage guides and wikis are different:

[jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jigsaw) wiki:

> Project Jigsaw is a sub-project of OpenJDK that aims to provide a standard module system for the Java SE platform. Originally targetted at Java 7 it was postponed first to Java 8 and more recently to Java 9.
>
> Originally the scope of the project was to provide modularisation for the JDK itself. This scope has been expanded to make the module system part of the Java Platform.
>
> The Jigsaw project is closely related to the Penrose Project that is looking at interoperability between Jigsaw and OSGi.
> w project is closely related to the Penrose Project that is looking at interoperability between Jigsaw and OSGi.

[java-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-module) wiki:

> A module is a named, self-describing collection of code and data. Its code is organized as a set of packages containing types, i.e., Java classes and interfaces; its data includes resources and other kinds of static information. The only module known specifically to the module system, in any case, is the base module, which is named java.base
>
> A module is described using a module-info which itself is a new construct added in java-9 to provide a module definition.
>
> Module names, like package names, must not conflict. The recommended way to name a module is to use the reverse-domain-name pattern that has long been recommended for naming packages. The name of a module will, therefore, often be a prefix of the names of its exported packages, but this relationship is not mandatory.
>
> Module declarations are part of the Java programming language, rather than a language or notation of their own, for several reasons. One of the most important is that module information must be available at both compile time and run time in order to achieve fidelity across phases, i.e., to ensure that the module system works in the same way at both compile time and run time. This, in turn, allows many kinds of errors to be prevented or, at least, reported earlier—at compile time—when they are easier to diagnose and repair.
>
> The Java SE 9 Platform Specification will use the module system to divide the platform into a set of modules. An implementation of the Java SE 9 Platform might contain all of the platform modules or, possibly, just some of them.
>
> A java.lang.Module represents a run-time module, either named or unnamed.
>
> Named modules have a name and are constructed by the Java Virtual Machine when a graph of modules is defined to the Java virtual machine to create a module layer.
>
> An unnamed module does not have a name. There is an unnamed module for each ClassLoader, obtained by invoking its getUnnamedModule method. All types that are not in a named module are members of their defining class loader's unnamed module.
>
> The package names that are parameters or returned by methods defined in this class are the fully-qualified names of the packages as defined in section 6.5.3 of The Java™ Language Specification, for example, "java.lang".

In the [Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) `Merge` only covers duplicate Qs and I have failed to find clear guidance anywhere on the difference between merging for tags and synonymising but seem to recall that the latter is reversible, *in extremis*, and the former is not, so synonyms are generally preferred.

There are just enough users qualified to propose and carry a synonym, in either direction. A merge should not be imposed upon subject matter experts  when it seems they do not want even a synonymisation, and lack of such has little significance for other users.

However a clean up may, as usual, be appropriate.