# Add tag [jpms] and make existing [jigsaw] tag a synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The Java Platform Module System (JPMS) is one of the key new features introduced in Java 9 in 2017.

Many projects are working with issues related to forward compatibility and backward compatibility with the new module system.  I was just preparing to write such a question and was surprised there is no existing jpms tag.

There is a tag [jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jigsaw) which represents the identical concept, however [Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) was completed with the release of JPMS.  From that link:

> The module system itself, specified by [JSR 376](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/) and implemented by [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261), was merged into JDK 9 build 111 in March 2016.

I recommend a new tag [jpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpms) be created as a synonym of [jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jigsaw), but also that [jpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpms) become the primary tag of the set of questions.

- There are presently [542 questions mentioning JPMS](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jpms+)
- Only [29 JPMS questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jpms+%5Bjigsaw%5D) also have the [jigsaw] tag
- The Jigsaw tag has [312 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jigsaw).

Related tags:

- [java-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-module) (previous [merge request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372709/merge-tags-jigsaw-and-java-module)) which is a broader concept and could include other modular systems like OSGi or build modules such as in Maven
- [module-info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/module-info) The actual class file implementing JPMS, so could be more specific regarding implementation details

Comment: How would you feel about making the master tag [[tag:java-master-platform-system]] in order to avoid the potentially confusing initialism?

Comment: If you meant "java-platform-module-system" I'm all for it (assuming the abbreviation is a synonym)

Comment: Ugh, yeah, see the problem? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now done, and I didn't even [screw up the name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399621/add-tag-jpms-and-make-existing-jigsaw-tag-a-synonym/399623#comment784059_399621)!<sup>*</sup>

[java-platform-module-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-platform-module-system) ← [jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jigsaw)

[java-platform-module-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-platform-module-system) ← [jpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpms)

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> I don't think.</sub>